# Number of homotopically inequivalent loops on a surface

Tags: general-topology, riemannian-geometry, homotopy-theory, geodesic

> ***Q.*** What is the largest number of pairwise disjoint, 
>   [homotopically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy) inequivalent,
>   simple closed curves 
>   that can be drawn on a surface $S$ of genus $g$?

---

[image]

          

<sup>Genus-$4$ surface. Image from a [Mathematica StackExchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20914/194) answer of @whuber.</sup>

---

For example, I *think* I see $9$ cycles on the above $g=4$ surface.

My question is surely answered in the literature, in which case a pointer would suffice.

Comment: In general the answer is $3g-3$. One can calculate this using Euler characteristic combined with the fact that when the maximum is achieved, each component of the complement will be homeomorphic to a 3-punctured sphere.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Thank you!

Comment: @LeeMosher for $g>1$, yes? for $g=2$, aren't there $3$ also?

Comment: Yes, for $g>1$.