# Number of homotopically inequivalent loops that pairwise intersect at most once

Tags: general-topology, riemannian-geometry, homotopy-theory, geodesic

This is a follow-up to my previous question,
"[Number of homotopically inequivalent loops on a surface](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2864877/237)":

> ***Q.*** What is the largest number of 
>   [homotopically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy) inequivalent,
>   simple closed curves, 
>   *each pair of which intersects in at most one point*, 
>   that can be drawn on a surface $S$ of genus $g$?

The previous question required the loops to be pairwise disjoint.
@LeeMosher answered: $3g - 3$. 
For $g=4$, allowing the loops to intersect increases 
the count from $3g{-}3=9$ to at least
$13$:

---

[image: JeffE]

          

<sup>Figure by [Jeff Erickson *here*](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/pubs/octagons.html).</sup>

---

But I have no confidence that $13$ is the max here.
I would be interested to know if there is some general theory that bounds
the loops according to their intersections.

Comment: Indeed $13$ is not the maximum. There is another one which intersects the following curves exactly once (and the others zero times): the leftmost black curve, the adjacent red curve; the adjacent green curve; and the outer black curve. But I do not know the maximum, and I have a vague memory that this is a hard problem.

Comment: [This article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.05658) by Josh Greene is probably the state of the art.

Comment: @MikeMiller: Excellent: $\lesssim g^2 \log g$.